# Rectangle intersections

Tags: visual-studio, methods, structure

I'm trying to make a program using WindowsForms with visualC++ to move one rectangle (CJ) through keyboard (using rectangle structures) and intersect it with another rectangle (C1) from the right, left, botton or top. So that when that happens it will automatically move to the same direction I was holding the key to move it, and until it passes all the rectangles (C1) that were on the way. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Show your code and clarify your problem

Comment: I actually solve the problem. It was easier than I expected. However this is what I was talking about: if (mapa[i][j] == 5 && CJ.IntersectsWith(C1) && ultima == Direcciones::Derecha)
 {
  buffer->Graphics->DrawRectangle(Pens::Transparent, X, Y, 32, 32);
  { dx = 10;}

Comment: I was using a matrix to make a game where a character could slide through blocks of ice. Notice that it will move without me trying to press a key when it's over those rectangles i created previously. Thanks anyway.